# Trying to create a method that take in the position of the mouse click and should return a cell number that is the selected cell

Tags: java, function, for-loop, processing

I want to create and call a method to check if a click happened over the grid. This method should take in the position of the mouse click and should return a cell number that is the selected cell. If a cell was clicked on, you need to determine which cell was clicked in and return that cell
number. Make sure that if a cell was already selected, and the user didn’t select a new cell, the old
selected cell still stays selected. If the user clicked in a cell, and that specific cell
was already selected, it should be unselected. In this case, it should return -1.
I did this to get the cell number but cannot make sure it stays selected and not able to return -1 to unselect.

```
int cellSelected(int x, int y){
  int selected=-2;
  int left=40;

  for(int num=0; num<=12*8; num++)
  {
    int col = num%8;
    int row = num/8;
    left = 40+CELL_SIZE*col;
    int right = left+CELL_SIZE;
    int top = 40+CELL_SIZE*row;
    int bottom = top+CELL_SIZE;
    if (x >= left && x < right && y >= top && y < bottom)
    {
      selected = num;

    }
   }
  return selected;
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76. My mistake. I did not read carefully.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the index of a cell, it is sufficient to divide the relative mouse position (in relation to the origin of the grid), by the size of a cell.

```java
int cellSelected(int x, int y){

     // position of the mouse relative to the grid
     int px = x - 40;
     int py = y - 40;

     // evaluate if the mouse is in the grid, return -1 else
     int cols = 8;
     int rows = 12;
     if (px < 0 || py < 0 || px > cols*CELL_SIZE || px > cols*CELL_SIZE) {
         return -1;
     }

     // calculate cell index (row and column of the cell)
     int col = px / CELL_SIZE;
     int row = py / CELL_SIZE;

     // return index of the cell
     return rows*cols + col;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that part. Now if  want to return -1 if i click on the same cell again, how do I do that?? Please help.

Comment: @ArshdeepSekhon You've to store the index of the last cell which was "clicked" and to evaluate if it is clicked again.